# How to mask [PAD] and [SEP] tokens to prevent their prediction and loss calculation for NER task on BERT models?

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to fine-tune BERT model for NER tagging task using [tensorflow official nlp toolkit](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/be0b836562d34ecd703d5d9e9e24c36624aeb3ac/official/nlp). I found there's already a [bert token classifier class](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/871c4e0a393ef4385534bee55354a5df8aa1ccf4/official/nlp/modeling/models/bert_token_classifier.py) which i wanted to use. Looking at the code inside, I don't see any masking to prevent tag prediction and loss calculation for paddings and [SEP] token. I think the prevention is possible, just I don't know how? I wanted to prevent this for faster training and also one of the [blog](https://gab41.lab41.org/lessons-learned-fine-tuning-bert-for-named-entity-recognition-4022a53c0d90) mentioned some weird behaviour when not masked.

Anybody has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution?
I'm doing the same task and I found the PADDING TOKEN is dominating the prediction. Passing in an attention mask didn't do anything so I manually chopped down the sequences to just 100 tokens long, and it improves.

Comment: Take a look at the custom loss function in this blog: https://keras.io/examples/nlp/ner_transformers/#compile-and-fit-the-model

Comment: I don't understand the code completely. But seems like its skipping losses of special tokens including paddings (using masking) while calculating average loss.